# Getting specific Node Value from XML and add to ArrayLIst

Tags: android, xpath, arraylist, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this

```
<reg>
  <user>
       <Name> abc</Name>
       <Email> abc@xyz.com</Email>
       <picture> sdCard/imges.145.jpg </Picture>
       <Date> 12/12/2012</Date>
  </user>
  <user>
       <Name> abc dfg</Name>
       <Email> ertdg@xyz.com</Email>
       <picture> sdCard/imges.145.jpg </Picture>
       <Date> 23/12/2013</Date>
  </user>
</reg>
```

i want to get values of specific nodes and add them to ArrayList to show the in ListView
I have tried this code but it only gives values for Last Record

```
Users setUser = new Users();
final ArrayList<Users> uData = new ArrayList<Users>();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

                XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


                String expression = "/reg/user/Name";
                System.out.println(expression);

                NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
                   setUser.setName(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());

               }
                String expression1 = "/reg/user/Email";
                System.out.println(expression1);

              NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression1).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(nodeList1.item(i).getTextContent());
                   setUser.setEmail(nodeList1.item(i).getTextContent());
               }
                String expression2 = "/reg/user/Picture";
                System.out.println(expression2);

                NodeList nodeList2 = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression2).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(nodeList2.item(i).getTextContent());
                   setUser.setimage(nodeList2.item(i).getTextContent());
               }
                String expression3 = "/reg/user/LastEdited";
                System.out.println(expression3);

                NodeList nodeList3 = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression3).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList3.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(nodeList3.item(i).getTextContent());
                   setUser.setDate(nodeList3.item(i).getTextContent()); 


                }  uData.add(setUser);
```

How can i make this to show all records ?

Comment: how do u identify the specific node?

Comment: here in my code i am identifying the node by XPATH expression . . .

Comment: Your setUser object replaces when the for loop iterates.And your adding setUser  to uData at end of forloop. So only the last object will be added to the array list.Thats why you are getting the last record only

Comment: i know this reason the question is that how can i make this happen in 1 (outer loop) so i can get values n all 4 nodes and add it to ArrayList, the way i am doing it by Xpath i have to run a saperate loop for each nod to get its values and put it in NodeList...

Comment: In your user tag there are only three child tag. And in the expression you are checking for Picture and LastEdited. So the contents of the User tag varies.So i guess the count of nodeList1 ,nodeList2,nodeList3 will also be different right?. I personly use simplexml serialization for these kind of operations.http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Comment: oh i am sorry for that, all user tags have same number of children ... see the updated xml..

Comment: oh.Instead of adding to the object  u can keep  temperory list for name,image,date,email.Now you have all elements in seperate array. Since all list has same no of elements, You can start another loop. For(int i=0;i<name.size()>;i++){ uData= new UData(); uData.setImage=name.get(i).getname(); uData.setDate=date(i).getDate; etc etc .Now the object is ready and add to uData.add(uData); }. But this will not be the best solution, this would cause serious performance issue. Try simplexml if u can, its pretty easy to handle

Comment: if simpleXML is best way to do it , i will try it.. thanks for the suggestion . . .

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code only gives values for Last Record already explained by @playmaker420 in comment. To fix it, you can try to loop through `<user>` elements instead of looping through each `<name>`, `<email>`, `<picture>`, and `<date>` separately :

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/reg/user";

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Users setUser = new Users();
    Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

    String name = el.getElementsByTagName("Name").item(0).getTextContent();
    setUser.setName(name);

    String email = el.getElementsByTagName("Email").item(0).getTextContent();
    setUser.setEmail(email);

    String picture = el.getElementsByTagName("picture").item(0).getTextContent();
    setUser.setimage(picture);

    String date = el.getElementsByTagName("Date").item(0).getTextContent();
    setUser.setDate(date);

    uData.add(setUser);
}
```

Comment: its giving last records for 2 times  . .

Comment: hmm.. I suspect you still have another `uData.add(setUser);` outside `for` loop? That will cause the last record added to list for 2nd time.